Is there a straight forward way to building an android apk through flet?
Currently I have the latest versions of Flutter, Dart, Flet and other packages I used in my project. But this specific issue im finding it hard to just simply create an android apk using flet's command "flet build apk --v". I come across an error that my source.properties file is unavailable which is true but for this exact reason i have installed lastest versions of the ndk but still my projects no matter how many i create are still set to the ndk version that has no source.properties. Ive been using pycharm for the flet app and building too.
How can i resolve the issue;
Build failed because: FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.
1: Task failed with an exception.

What went wrong: A problem occurred configuring project ':serious_python_android'.


[CXX1101] NDK at C:\Users\y\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\25.1.8937393 did not have a source.properties file


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.

What went wrong: Failed to query the value of property 'buildFlowServiceProperty'.


Could not isolate value org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.statistics.BuildFlowService$Parameters_Decorated@70799a7b of type BuildFlowService.Parameters
A problem occurred configuring project ':serious_python_android'.
> [CXX1101] NDK at C:\Users\TEN\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\25.1.8937393 did not have a source.properties file


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
==============================================================================

BUILD FAILED in 25s (  ●   ) Building .apk for Android ⏳...    26.8s Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1 [19:24:51] Deleting Flutter bootstrap directory C:\Users\TEN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\flet_flutter_build_oH4Ieb41FN
           Run subprocess: ['C:\\src\\flutter\\flutter\\bin\\flutter.BAT', '--version'] [19:24:52] Error building Flet app - see the log of failed command above.

